# How to make sprite follow another sprite in Phaser 3

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

How would you go about making a sprite follow another sprite in Phaser 3?

An example would be the parts of a snake in [slither.io](http://slither.io)

In Phaser 2 there was the `addChild` ([see here](http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/33105-solvedhow-to-create-sprite-followpin-another-sprite-like-gamedebugbody/)), which in Phaser 3 only exists for containers... There are many examples on how to accomplish this in Phaser 2, but I can't figure it out for Phaser 3...

Alternatively I could create my own Path array like in [this example](https://loonride.com/learn/phaser/slither-io-part-2). But I am quite sure there should be an easier solution.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds similar to my question here, [String of moving sprites following the player, most efficient way to do it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44196855/string-of-moving-sprites-following-the-player-most-efficient-way-to-do-it)

In the end I just used my own suggestion as mentioned in the opening question:

- Create a Phaser.Group of sprites
- Use array of like 9999 locationpoints (x,y)
- Keep track of array index for head locations
- For each frame, save value of head locations at index position in array
- Update positions of the following sprites accordingly in `.update()`
- index+1 (if larger than say 9999 then index=0)

That is what I used in the [final game](http://www.coolmath-games.com/0-impossible-snake) ;)